# if i use firebase integration in app ,, Google Allowed to Approve my App in Google Play?

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase, publish

**if i use fire-base integration in app ,Google Allowed to Approve my App in Google Play??**`if i use firebase integration in  app ,, Google Allowed to Approve my App in Google Play??`

Comment: can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I want to create app which use database from firebase, if i use firebase google approve my app???

Answer (score 1):

Approval or rejection of an app for the Google Play Store is not dependent on whether the app use Firebase or not. The two are completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer by Frank clarifies in one line, approval or rejection has got nothing to do with the tools or technologies that are used to develop the app.

I found this great answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-apps-get-rejected-when-they-are-submitted-to-the-Android-Google-Play-Store), pasting here too. Below are the few conditions that might cause a rejection in Google PlayStore.

- App that contain copy right material
- App that places ads on home screen
- App with push notification ads
- App that updates its app other than google server
- App with malicious functions and does activities without user notified
- App the has no proper content licensing declared
- App that the shows sexual conent and promote pronography without prior decaration of content rating
- Same apps with multiple package names
- App that promotes violence and bullying
- App the steals personal and confidential information from phone
- App that promotes gambling
- App that interface with the system without the user getting that to know
- App the uses excessive keywords,mislead keywords,fraudalant installs,paid or fake reviews, created by automation to,provide a webview of unauthorized , that has primary functanilty to drive traffic to website etc
- App that send emails,messages without providing the user with the abity to confirm content and intended recipient
- App Promotion via ads on websites,simulated systems, alerts, app notifications
- Promotion or install tactics which cause redirection to google play or download the app without user action
- Developers charging for apps and downloads from google play must do so by using google play payment system only
- The pysical address must be given if you are having in app purchaces
  Ads must be shown inside the app and should not force user to click the ads in any manner or place the ads near buttons etc where they are clickes miatakely
  Impersonation and deceptive behaviour

[Read this for more info](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/)